# NodeJS incorrect `console.log` Date value

Tags: node.js

NodeJS outputs incorrect Date value in `console.log`

Assuming:
`var todayDate = new Date();`

Machine timezone: GMT+0530 / IST

Following are results:

**#1**

`console.log ('Today  date:', todayDate);`

**Output:** 020-04-04T09:54:29.107Z

**#2**
`console.log ('Today  date as UTC:', todayDate.toUTCString());`

**Output:** Today  date as UTC: Sat, 04 Apr 2020 09:54:29 GMT

**#3**
`console.log ('Today  date as string:', todayDate.toString());`

**Output:** Today  date as string: Sat Apr 04 2020 15:24:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

I am getting Output#1 whereas expected output is #3.

The Chrome browser shows same result as #3 which I expected with NodeJS since it runs on Chrome engine.

Please explain why NodeJS not output in local date/time.

Comment: What output are you getting instead of the expected one? I get the exact same output in node (v12) and in my chrome browser, i.e. `Sat Apr 04 2020 12:45:57 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)` in my case.

Comment: I am getting Output#1 whereas expected output is #3.

Comment: Ah now I get it - interesting, didn't know that. Seems the default formatter differs in the implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally the `Date` object is the same in both chrome and node. It contains the number of seconds elapsed since the UNIX epoch. However different platforms chose to display it differently. Node.js calls `toISOString()`, while Chorome calls `toString()` (`toString()` in Node.js will return the same as in Chrome).

Comment: Please provide a reference to support your answer. Is it mentioned in NodeJS documentation?

Comment: I don't think it's mentioned anywhere. In the code base https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/17f323ebfaf4b6f15e994412113d1e856a2e0ffc/lib/internal/util/inspect.js#L883, you can see it gets formatted with Date.toString() if the Date.getTime() is NaN, and with Date.toISOString() otherwise. Playing around with the code a little bit, apparently Date.toISOString() throws and error when the time is NaN and toString() returns 'Inavlid Date' in V8.

Comment: You can actually try it (new Date(undefined)).toISOString() -> Error and (new Date(undefined)).toString() -> 'Invalid Date'. new Date(undefined) prints 'Invalid Date', so it's formated with toString(). So according to the code base it gets formated with toString() if the time is NaN, toISOString() otherwise.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, after setting TZ in docker, and confirming it was fine in the image... I was so perplexed where the UTC was coming from with all my custom settings.  ty

Comment: btw, I used [This work around with Morgan](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/node-js-logs-in-local-timezone-on-morgan-and-winston-9e98b2b9ca45)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that behaviour. In my case I was looping through unix dates from database:

```
    console.log(endunix); //epoch date
    console.log(endutc); // wrong date that will be fixed from unixdate
    let nowadatautc = new Date(endunix*1000);
    console.log(nowadatautc); // new date
let sql2 = "update schedule a set end_time_utc='"+nowadatautc+"' where a.`event_id` > 374 and a.`sport_id` = 5";
```

and I get:

```
1645328100
2022-02-20T03:05:00.000Z
2022-02-20T03:35:00.000Z
update schedule a set end_time_utc='Sun Feb 20 2022 04:35:00 GMT+0100 (czas środkowoeuropejski standardowy)' where a.`event_id` > 374 and a.`sport_id` = 5
```